# conditionalPanel does not show up textinput based on choices made at selectizeInput | R Shiny

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I am trying to create a few textInput-fields based on the choices of my selectizeInput.

So if the user selects `somename22`, the UI should add a new textInput. Same for `somename33`

**The MRE:**

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(12,
           selectizeInput(
             inputId = "select_id", label = NULL, multiple  = TRUE,
             width = "100%",
             choices =
               list(
                 "Select value ..." = "",
                 "somename22",               
                 "somename33"
               )
           ))
  ),
  fluidRow(
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.select_id != null && input.select_id.indexOf('22') > -1",
      column(4,
             textInput("textid_1", NULL)
      )
    ),
    
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.select_id != null && input.select_id.indexOf('33') > -1",
      column(4,
             textInput("textid_2", NULL)
      )
    )
  )
  
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

btw in the real app the choices-names in selectize are a little bit more complex because of Katex, so I need to use some kind of partial matching like `indexOf`.

Any hints, maybe? :)

**EDIT:**

The approach of @stefan works pretty well for "normal" strings, but unfortunately I have to deal with `katex` choices. So the actual MRE looks like this:

**MRE v2:**

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    tags$head(
      tags$link(rel="stylesheet", 
                href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.10.1/dist/katex.min.css", 
                integrity="sha384-dbVIfZGuN1Yq7/1Ocstc1lUEm+AT+/rCkibIcC/OmWo5f0EA48Vf8CytHzGrSwbQ",
                crossorigin="anonymous"),
      HTML('<script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.10.1/dist/katex.min.js" integrity="sha384-2BKqo+exmr9su6dir+qCw08N2ZKRucY4PrGQPPWU1A7FtlCGjmEGFqXCv5nyM5Ij" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>'),
      HTML('<script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.10.1/dist/contrib/auto-render.min.js" integrity="sha384-kWPLUVMOks5AQFrykwIup5lo0m3iMkkHrD0uJ4H5cjeGihAutqP0yW0J6dpFiVkI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>'),
      HTML('
          <script>
            document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
            renderMathInElement(document.body, {
            delimiters: [{left: "$", right: "$", display: false}]
            });
          })
          </script>')
    ),
    
    column(
      12,
      selectizeInput(
        inputId = "select_id", label = NULL, multiple = TRUE,
        width = "100%",
        choices = list(
          "Select a value ..."="",
          "\\text{var1 } x_i",
          "\\text{var2 } n_i"
        ),
        options = list(render = I("
                 {
                 item: function(item, escape) {var html = katex.renderToString(item.label);
                 return '<div>' + html + '</div>';},
                 option: function(item, escape) {var html = katex.renderToString(item.label);
                 return '<div>' + html + '</div>';}
                 }"
        ))
      ))
  ),
  fluidRow(
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.select_id != null && input.select_id.indexOf('\text{var1 } x_i') > -1",
      column(
        4,
        textInput("textid_1", NULL)
      )
    ),
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.select_id != null && input.select_id.indexOf('var2') > -1",
      column(
        4,
        textInput("textid_2", NULL)
      )
    )
  )
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE** I have only some basic knowledge of JS. But the issue is that `input.select_id` is an array not a string. Hence, when doing `input.select_id.indexOf` you are calling the array method `indexOf` which looks for an exact match. Instead you have to "loop" over the array elments to check for a partial match using e.g.

```
input.select_id.some(element => element.includes('\\\\text{var1 } x_i'))
```

which will return `true` if there is a match for one of the array elements.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    tags$head(
      tags$link(rel="stylesheet", 
                href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.10.1/dist/katex.min.css", 
                integrity="sha384-dbVIfZGuN1Yq7/1Ocstc1lUEm+AT+/rCkibIcC/OmWo5f0EA48Vf8CytHzGrSwbQ",
                crossorigin="anonymous"),
      HTML('<script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.10.1/dist/katex.min.js" integrity="sha384-2BKqo+exmr9su6dir+qCw08N2ZKRucY4PrGQPPWU1A7FtlCGjmEGFqXCv5nyM5Ij" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>'),
      HTML('<script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.10.1/dist/contrib/auto-render.min.js" integrity="sha384-kWPLUVMOks5AQFrykwIup5lo0m3iMkkHrD0uJ4H5cjeGihAutqP0yW0J6dpFiVkI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>'),
      HTML('
          <script>
            document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
            renderMathInElement(document.body, {
            delimiters: [{left: "$", right: "$", display: false}]
            });
          })
          </script>')
    ),
    
    column(
      12,
      selectizeInput(
        inputId = "select_id", label = NULL, multiple = TRUE,
        width = "100%",
        choices = list(
          "Select a value ..."="",
          "\\text{var1 } x_i",
          "\\text{var2 } n_i"
        ),
        options = list(render = I("
                 {
                 item: function(item, escape) {var html = katex.renderToString(item.label);
                 return '<div>' + html + '</div>';},
                 option: function(item, escape) {var html = katex.renderToString(item.label);
                 return '<div>' + html + '</div>';}
                 }"
        ))
      ))
  ),
  fluidRow(
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.select_id != null && input.select_id.some(element => element.includes('\\\\text{var1 } x_i'))",
      column(
        4,
        textInput("textid_1", "textid_1")
      )
    ),
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.select_id != null && input.select_id.some(element => element.includes('var2'))",
      column(
        4,
        textInput("textid_2", "textid_2")
      )
    )
  )
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

**Original answer**

The issue is that your `choices` are called `somename22` and `somename33` while in the ´conditionalPanel`your are looking for`22`and`33`. Fixing that will solve your issue and your` textInput`s will show up:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(
      12,
      selectizeInput(
        inputId = "select_id", label = NULL, multiple = TRUE,
        width = "100%",
        choices =
          list(
            "Select value ..." = "",
            "somename22",
            "somename33"
          )
      )
    )
  ),
  fluidRow(
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.select_id != null && input.select_id.indexOf('somename22') > -1",
      column(
        4,
        textInput("textid_1", NULL)
      )
    ),
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.select_id != null && input.select_id.indexOf('somename33') > -1",
      column(
        4,
        textInput("textid_2", NULL)
      )
    )
  )
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you!
But that is again a exact matching approach and unfornately I need some partial matching, because the original choices are combinations of katex code (e.g. like `\\text{kum. h\u00E4ufig } H_i` and I cant figure out how to check for them

Comment: I have edit my question also to make things clearer

Comment: I just added an update which now checks for a partial match.

Comment: that's exactly what I was looking for, thank you :)

(btw I just figure out, one can also reach this with a setName approach and using the values in `indexOf`. But your approach is a better way imo